# Symfony: Save multiple same objects

Tags: symfony1, save

I have a page that shows 3 Objects (they are the same class). 
I want to save them.
Unfortunaly only the latest one gets updated. All other seems to be invalid.

So my idea was to give them unique names: testObject_1[text1], testObject_2[text1].
This works as I can see it in the source code.

But how can I pass this name to form->save() in order to get the POST-reply filtered by this name (testObject_1) and then save it?

Or is there something more easier?

Thank you
Tobias Kaminsky

Comment: Could you give us what you did to make it work. I don't get it when you say : "So my idea was to give them unique names: testObject_1[text1], testObject_2[text1]. This works as I can see it in the source code." Reg;

Answer (score 0):

I solved it:

```
$temp->bind($request->getParameter("testObject_$i"), $request->getFiles("testObject_$i"));
```

(where $i is an Index stored in the database)